# How can I check a collection is a view?

Tags: pymongo

I need to do some actions on all collections. I list them with some simple code like that:

```py
for collection_name in db.list_collection_names():
   # do something that work only on collection that are not a view
```

I get all collections including the views. Which is not working with what I want. So:
How can I check a collection is a view?
How can I filter out the views when getting the list of collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list_collections()` and filter out items that are not collections. Creating a view adds a `system.views` collection, the example below filters that out too.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

for collection_name in db.list_collections(filter={'type': 'collection', 'name': {'$ne': 'system.views'}}):
    print(collection_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Filter is working and when using list_collections, I have also access to collection["type"] to know if it is really a collection or a view.